# Amazon Linux 2023 AMI Permissions

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I'm setting up a new EC2 Instance with AMI Linux 2023. (I'm super new to Linux/AMI). I followed this tutorial on the AWS website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2023.html. I'm little confused about the setup and permissions for document web root `var/www` directory.

Here are my groups:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ groups
ec2-user adm wheel apache systemd-journal
```

The tutorial tells me to do the following:

Change the group ownership of /var/www and its contents to the apache group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
```

Add group write permission

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www && find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
```

To add group write permissions, recursively change the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

Is it a security issue to add `ec2-user` and to add "group write permission" to the `apache` group in the production server?